# Using mapply to calculate the mean of more than one list

Tags: r, mean, lapply, mapply

The dataset

```
firstList  <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
secondList <- list(c = 7:9, d = 10:12)
```

I am trying to calculate the mean of multiple lists with mapply.

```
mapply(mean, firstList, secondList)
```

It did not work because `mean` only averages its first argument as per 
[Using mapply with mean function on a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825381/using-mapply-with-mean-function-on-a-matrix)

This works correctly:

```
mapply(mean, firstList)
mapply(mean, secondList)
```

I then tried `lapply` to supply one list at a time to `mapply`

```
lapply(c(firstList, secondList), function(x) mapply(mean, x))
```

The output was NOT the mean but the individual lists

What I need is how to calculate the `mean` of multiple list using `mapply`. I also would appreciate an explanation as of why `mapply` did not return the lists `mean'

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `?mean`, the usage is

```
mean(x, ...)
```

In the `mapply`, we have 'x' and 'y', so we can concatenate the corresponding `list` elements to make a single 'x' and then take the `mean`

```
mapply(function(x,y) mean(c(x,y)), firstList, secondList)
#a b 
#5 8
```

same as,

```
mean(c(1:3, 7:9))
#[1] 5
```

---

If we are using a combination of `apply` functions, we can concatenate with `Map`, and then loop the `list` elements with `sapply` to get the `mean`

```
sapply(Map(c, firstList, secondList), mean)
# a b 
#5 8
```

Or if the `lengths` of `list` elements are the same, we can use `colMeans` as the `mapply/c` output is a `matrix` without `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`

```
colMeans(mapply(c, firstList, secondList)) 
#a b 
#5 8
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are saying that the number of parameters for the function must equal to the number of lists to be averaged, correct?

Comment: @RagyIsaac It's related to the arguments in `mean`, which can take only `x`, where as with `mapply/Map`, you have x, y,... depending on the number of lists.  Also, if there are many lists, instead of specifying `function(x,y,z, u)...`, you can just use `c` to concatenate all the corresponding list elements and then get the `mean` with `sapply` or use `colMeans` if the lengths are the same.

Comment: @RagyIsaac Another option is `library(data.table); rbindlist(list(firstList, secondList))[, lapply(.SD, mean)]`

Comment: Why lapply(c(firstList, secondList), function(x) mapply(mean, x)) did not work?

Comment: @RagyIsaac  If you look at the output of `c(firstList, secondList)`, it is a list of length 4.  `lapply` will loop through the list elements.  Each list element is a vector.  Applying `mapply` on that vector, is like looping again each single vector element, and doing the `mean` is just doing the `mean` of a single value.

Comment: @RagyIsaac If you want the mean of each list element after the concatenation, `lapply(c(firstList, secondList), function(x) mapply(mean, list(x)))` or just `lapply(c(firstList, secondList), mean)`